# Unable to find element in

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have started learning Selenium using python. I want to click checkbox (Workdays 10-11). Please refer respective HTML Tag as shown below. I have tried using Xpath but id in the tag keeps changing every execution. Also, I have tried using Class name but no-use.Can you please advice?

```html
<div id="EAACAAA_b3" xscroll="1" onmouseleave="hidetreepager(this.firstChild)" onmouseenter="showtreepager(this.firstChild,event.srcElement,event)" onmousemove="showtreepager(this.firstChild,event.srcElement,event)" style="width: 347px; height: 300px; overflow: auto;"><div id="members_tree" treeid="members" mode="crittree" multiselect="true" autowidth="true" enabled="" class="xcriteriadropdown-members" onclick="clickcrittree(this,event)" singleselect="03344C6E"><div class="treenoderoot" nodeid="0" state="1"><span class="treetext"><span></span><img src="images/blank.gif" style="display:none"><img src="images/checkbox_checked.png" align="absmiddle" class="treestate"><a href="#">No selection</a></span><div class="treechildren" style="display:block;padding-left:0px" id="ext-gen8"><div class="treenode" nodeid="1" state="0" id="ext-gen10"><div class="treetext"><img src="images/blank.gif" nalign="absmiddle"><img src="images/checkbox_unchecked.png" class="treestate" nalign="absmiddle"><a href="#">Workdays 10-11</a></div></div><div class="treenode" nodeid="2" state="0"><div class="treetext"><img src="images/blank.gif" nalign="absmiddle"><img src="images/checkbox_unchecked.png" class="treestate" nalign="absmiddle"><a href="#">Workdays 08-10, 11-16</a></div></div><div class="treenode" nodeid="3" state="0"><div class="treetext" id="ext-gen11"><img src="images/blank.gif" nalign="absmiddle"><img src="images/checkbox_unchecked.png" class="treestate" nalign="absmiddle"><a href="#">Workdays 00-08, 16-24</a></div></div><div class="treenode" nodeid="4" state="0" id="ext-gen9"><div class="treetext" id="ext-gen7"><img src="images/blank.gif" nalign="absmiddle"><img src="images/checkbox_unchecked.png" class="treestate" nalign="absmiddle"><a href="#">Weekends and holidays</a></div></div></div></div></div><img src="resource.ashx?resname=Misc_Down16&amp;_dc=" 76d3ff65"="" border="0" style="position: absolute; left: -5000px; top: -5000px;" id="ext-gen5"><img src="resource.ashx?resname=Misc_Up16&amp;_dc=" 76d3ff65"="" border="0" style="position: absolute; left: -5000px; top: -5000px;" id="ext-gen6"></div>
```

[image]

```html
<div class="treenode" nodeid="1" state="0" id="ext-gen11"><div class="treetext" id="ext-gen8"><img src="images/blank.gif" nalign="absmiddle"><img src="images/checkbox_unchecked.png" class="treestate" nalign="absmiddle" id="ext-gen7"><a href="#" id="ext-gen12">Workdays 10-11</a></div></div>
```

Comment: Please don't change the question based on which you have received well researched answers. Once you receive canonical answers changing the question can make all the existing answers invalid and may not be useful to future readers. If your requirement have changed feel free to raise a new question. StackOverflow contributors will be happy to help you out. For the time being I have reverted back the question to it's initial state.

Answer (score 0):

To identify the element `Workdays 10-11` use following xpath.

```
//a[text()='Workdays 10-11']
```

**Code:**

```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Workdays 10-11']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as ***Workdays 10-11*** you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *link_text*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Workdays 10-11").click()
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Workdays 10-11']").click()
  ```

---

Ideally to click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *LINK_TEXT*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Workdays 10-11"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Workdays 10-11']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I have updated question. Please advice